# How to resolve DecoderCallback not found in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, build

## Error while building the app in flutter

> Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode... Get
> java version from JAVA_HOME: C:\Program Files\Android\Android
> Studio\jbr The photo_manager java version is 17
> /C:/Users/shafi/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/photo_manager-2.8.1/lib/src/internal/image_provider.dart:71:5:
> Error: Type 'DecoderCallback' not found.
> DecoderCallback decode, // ignore: deprecated_member_use
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ /C:/Users/shafi/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/photo_manager-2.8.1/lib/src/internal/image_provider.dart:96:5:
> Error: Type 'DecoderCallback' not found.
> DecoderCallback decode, // ignore: deprecated_member_use
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ /C:/Users/shafi/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/photo_manager-2.8.1/lib/src/internal/image_provider.dart:71:5:
> Error: 'DecoderCallback' isn't a type.
> DecoderCallback decode, // ignore: deprecated_member_use
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ /C:/Users/shafi/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/photo_manager-2.8.1/lib/src/internal/image_provider.dart:96:5:
> Error: 'DecoderCallback' isn't a type.
> DecoderCallback decode, // ignore: deprecated_member_use
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ /C:/Users/shafi/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_blurhash-0.7.0/lib/src/blurhash_image.dart:32:48:
> Error: Type 'DecoderCallback' not found.   ImageStreamCompleter
> load(BlurHashImage key, DecoderCallback decode) =>
> OneFrameImageStreamCompleter(_loadAsync(key));
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ /C:/Users/shafi/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_blurhash-0.7.0/lib/src/blurhash_image.dart:32:48:
> Error: 'DecoderCallback' isn't a type.   ImageStreamCompleter
> load(BlurHashImage key, DecoderCallback decode) =>
> OneFrameImageStreamCompleter(_loadAsync(key));
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ /C:/Users/shafi/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_blurhash-0.7.0/lib/src/blurhash_widget.dart:218:42:
> Error: Type 'DecoderCallback' not found.   ImageStreamCompleter
> load(UiImage key, DecoderCallback decode) =>
> OneFrameImageStreamCompleter(_loadAsync(key));
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ /C:/Users/shafi/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_blurhash-0.7.0/lib/src/blurhash_widget.dart:218:42:
> Error: 'DecoderCallback' isn't a type.   ImageStreamCompleter
> load(UiImage key, DecoderCallback decode) =>
> OneFrameImageStreamCompleter(_loadAsync(key));
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where: Script 'C:\src\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\src\main\groovy\flutter.groovy'
>   line: 1350
> - What went wrong: Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.
>
> > Process 'command 'C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
>
> - Try:
>
> > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> > Run with --scan to get full insights.
>
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 16s Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with
> exit code 1
>
> Exited (1).

**There are a number of error in this project can you people help me to solve?!**

I am trying to buidl the app using flutter(dart). And while am doing this error occurs.

Answer (score 1):

`DecoderCallback` has been removed in Flutter 3.16, see the [release notes](https://docs.flutter.dev/release/release-notes/release-notes-3.16.0#framework).

The package author of [photo_manager](https://pub.dev/packages/photo_manager) has provided a new [prerelease version](https://pub.dev/packages/photo_manager/versions/3.0.0-dev.5) that should address the issue, however take notes that it introduced some breaking changes. See the [migration guide](https://github.com/fluttercandies/flutter_photo_manager/blob/main/MIGRATION_GUIDE.md).

To use the prerelease version of photo_manager, use it in your pubspec file like this:

```yaml
dependencies:
  photo_manager: ^3.0.0-dev.5
```

---

If you're not using the photo_manager package directly, chances are one or more of your dependencies depend on this package. You can see the list of packages that depend on photo_manager [here](https://pub.dev/packages?q=dependency%3Aphoto_manager).